# How can we change Three.js coordinate system to match DOM transform coordinates?

Tags: javascript, three.js

For example, how can we make position `0,0,0` in Three.js start at the top/left of the scene, like with DOM?

I'd like to make a sphere so that when position is 0,0,0 it will be at the top left, and it's size will be in CSS pixel dimensions and that this size will not change if the size of the viewport changes. If the size if 10, I'd like that to mean that a span of 10 CSS px is spanned on the screen (when Z=0).

---

EDIT: I'm moving this question to the relatively-new official Three.js forums that I wasn't aware of: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-can-we-make-three-js-scenes-use-dom-style-coordinates/962

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper orthographic (instead of perspective) projection matrix to fit the canvas size in pixel. An orthographic projection matrix is built as follow:

```
 S   0   0   0   |  S = 2 / right - left
 0   T   0   0   |  T = 2 / top - bottom
 0   0   U   0   |  U = -2 / far-near
 Tx  Ty  Tz  1   |
```

You can define the projection matrix as follow so that match world space with screen space in pixels (assuming a 4x4 matrix defined in a 16 floats array):

```
view[ 0] = 2.0 / (canvasWidth);
view[ 5] = 2.0 / -(canvasHeight);     // Negate to invert Y coordinates
view[10] = -2.0 / farClip - nearClip;
view[12] = -1.0;                      // Translate X so left border start at 0 
view[13] = 1.0;                       // Translate Y so top border start at 0 
view[14] = 0.0; 
view[15] = 1.0;
```

You now have to found a way to setup this on Three.js...

Comment: Thanks for the hint Sedenion. What are the right, left, top, bottom, far, near values? Is right == canvasWidth, left == 0?

Comment: right left top and bottom are related to the viewport `right - left` gives a width and  `top - bottom` give an height. far and near value are related to the near and far clipping planes. Yes in your case, `right` is `canvasWidth` and `Left` is implicitely `0` since you theorically cover all the canvas.